# Google storage service auth not working with cron job

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-iam

I have this `script.sh` file, to upload file to G-storage

```
gcloud auth  activate-service-account production-storage@123-testing.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file /opt/key.json

gsutil  cp  /tmp/sampeFile gs://mybuket/backup/1/
```

When i execute it using terminal, it works fine and upload the file to google storage

But when i run the script using cron job, `* * * * * /opt/script.sh` the script get executed but file does not get upload to G-storage

NO error is printed as well.

What am i doing wrong. Request for help ?

Comment: There's probably something wrong about the paths or permissions. You can add some debug output to the cronjob. I would add something like `cat /tmp/sampeFile` and `gcloud config get-value project` to it. Pipe that output to a file and go from there.

Comment: @Bhuvan: I am also facing the same issue. I have made changes in .boto file as well but facing the same issue.